# zf2 call a method from a Model in another Model

Tags: model-view-controller, zend-framework2

I have a couple of modules in ZF2 project. Each module has different model classes performing different required functions. Now I have method in a model class of first module which I want to call in the model class of second module. Is it possible to do so? if yes, how?

Comment: I've done things similar to what you're asking in ZF1, I instantiated objects in the controller that needed access to an additional controller's model, if that helps. Not sure how ZF2 would do it, and I found this forum link that may point you in the right direction http://forums.zend.com/viewtopic.php?t=8336

Comment: This is a very basic question, which is about how to include a file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be fairly simple. Firstly you need to include the two modules in your `application.config.php`

```
'modules' => array(
    'Module1',
    'Module2'
)
```

Then as a very basic example taken from your question:

```
<?php
namespace Module2\Model;

use Module1\Model\Class1;    

class Class2
{
    public function doSomething()
    {
        $class1 = new Class1();
        $class1->doSomething();
    }
}
```